# Testing GUI application using pygobject3 with pytest

Tags: unit-testing, user-interface, gtk, pytest, pygobject

I got a task to write some unit tests for devassistant (a helper program can help you set up your developing environment). It is written in Python and offers graphical user interface which is implemented with pygobject3. There are already unit tests, using pytest.
I wrote some basic tests, which work like this:

- create the main window (like the application was executed normally by a human) but do not call Gtk.main() - so that the main window won't show up
- simulate interactions with gui (clicking buttons, un/tinking checkboxes etc) or directly call their callbacks
- check if things are as expected (call asserts)

The actual problem is, that when the gui tests are passed and there are more tests after the gui tests, during doing the following tests an empty window (with just a title) shows up and pytest freezes (the empty window does't react and cannot be closed), so I must kill it. If I "move" the gui tests to the last position, they work normally.

Steps to reproduce:

- clone my repository https://github.com/jkoncick/devassistant - the actual commit adding the tests is https://github.com/jkoncick/devassistant/commit/e4296fcf7e1393a1140f3205304e54b9e8c62375
- (install all required python packages - they are in the requirements file)
- move the test_gui.py file into parent directory - so that the gui tests are not performed last but there are some tests after them
- in devassistant/gui/main_window.py delete line 81 with "self.main_win.hide()"
- run tests with "./setup.py test"
- after doing gui tests (they should pass) an empty window shows up and pytest freezes. If you do not delete the line "self.main_win.hide()", the window won't show but pytest freezes anyway

I am really helpless with it. Moving the gui test to be last works, but it is rather a workaround and I cannot assume it will work everywhere. I could not manage to "close" or "destroy" the main window so that it wouldn't show up and break the tests.
I tried these, but none worked:

`app.main_win.destroy()
app.main_win.emit('delete-event', None)
Gtk.main_quit()`

Do you please have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I finally solved this problem. And it was actually not a problem in Gtk. I was prejudiced that it was caused by Gtk_main() not exited properly or main_window not destroyed properly and stuck waiting for events (as described in the previous answer), but it was not the actual problem and now it works.

The problem was in run_window.py > RunLoggingHandler > emit() > Gdk.threads_enter() <- it froze here.
The 'logger' variable in logger.py was global and when a RunLoggingHandler was added into it ("logger.addHandler(self.tlh)" in run_window.py), it retained here and when emit() was called in following tests, it stuck here. Fixed it by clearing logger handlers after the tests:

`from devassistant.logger import logger`

`def teardown_method(self, method):
    logger.handlers = []`

Answer (score 1):

You always need to run a Gtk mainloop for widgets to behave properly. If you do you can quit the mainloop with `Gtk.main_quit()` from a signal callback /event. If you don't you will end up with a frozen window as you are not having a mainloop which takes care of painting widget content.

---

The fact that it **seems** to work if you run it last, is caused by `./setup.py test` is terminating and thus taking the whole process - including the gtk window - down.